# how to determine the number assigned to each letter in a cryptarithm?

Tags: loops, numbers, letters, cryptarithmetic-puzzle

I have an assignment that needs to solve a cryptarithm. But I cant understand the algorithms that I saw in the internet. Could anybody explain how to do this in simple words?

Comment: What algorithms have you tried?

Comment: getting all the possible combinations of characters in a string then compute for the sum to solve the cryptarithm. But its very slow

Comment: Have you done a frequency analysis of the ciphertext?

Comment: Giving links to the "algorithms you saw on the internet" would help us a lot. There are lots of different ways to solve these constraint problems, ranging in dificulty and complexity. How familiar are you with backtracking algorithms?

Answer (score 1):

As a general case, most Constraint Satisfaction Algorithms are a two step process, where a guessing (or branching) phase is followed by a deductive phase, where as many assignments as possible are found without guessing. (Think Sudoku, for example)

Example:

```
  S E N D
  M O R E
M O N E Y

First step: guess D=1 (remaining guesses = ...)

  S E N 1  | D=1
  M O R E
M O N E Y

Guess E = 1 (Remaining guesses = ...)

  S 1 N 1  | D = 1 | E = 1
  M O R 1
M O N 1 Y

We can now deduce that Y = 2 and that the carry value in the second column is 0

      0
  S 1 N 1  | D = 1 | E = 1, Y = 2
  M O R 1
M O N 1 2
```

When you reach a dead end, [backtrack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking)

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to solve this kind of problem with Genetic Algorithm, here is a solution using GA https://github.com/pauloremoli/cryptarithmetic